# Space between a/b differentiation with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to set a longer document and stumbled upon the following problem using `authoryear-comp`:

If I've set `uniquelist=minyear`, I get citations with NAME YEARa and NAME YEARb, if the author list is identical. So far, so good.

If I cite two papers within the same cite command, I get `YEARa,b`. Is it possible to get i) a space between , and b: `YEARa, b`; or ii) `YEARa, YEARb`?

This is a MWE for demo:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,dashed=false,style=authoryear-comp,uniquename=false,uniquelist=minyear,date=year,maxcitenames=2, useprefix=true,maxbibnames=99,mincrossrefs=99,sorting=ynt,sortcites=true,isbn=false,eprint=false,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Awesome Journal},
  volume = 3
}
@article{a2,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Another Journal},
  volume = 3
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{a1,a2}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Screenshot without space]

and there is no space in between the comma after a and the b.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I believe that the comma is sufficient to indicate that there are two different citations involved; different publishers have different preferences, but I think that most would prefer not to have a space in this position.

Comment: Well, it's true that the comma is sufficient, but the publisher requested a space there. But I'll go for the second option, repeating the year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding space can be done by adjusting the `biblatex` macro `cite:extradate`.  Here using the `\addthinspace` macro provided by `biblatex`

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{extradate}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\addthinspace\printfield{extradate}}}}
```

The second form requested can achieved by rewriting the `cite` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,dashed=false,style=authoryear-comp,uniquename=false,uniquelist=minyear,date=year,maxcitenames=2, useprefix=true,maxbibnames=99,mincrossrefs=99,sorting=ynt,sortcites=true,isbn=false,eprint=false,urldate=long]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Awesome Journal},
  volume = 3
}
@article{a2,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Another Journal},
  volume = 3
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{extradate}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\addthinspace\printfield{extradate}}}}

\begin{document}

\cite{a1,a2}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                       \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
             {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%  <---- punuctation
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}} % <---- instead of cite:extradate
             {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
     \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\cite{a1,a2}
\end{document}
```

You may have to do something similar for other citations commands. Their source code is to be found in `authoryear-comp.cbx`. See the `.log` file for the full path on your system.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `biblatex-ext`'s plug-in replacement for `authoryear-comp`, `ext-authoryear-comp`.

Then you just need to redefine `extradateonlycompcitedelim` to your liking.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-comp,
  sorting=ynt,
  uniquename=false,uniquelist=minyear,
  maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, 
  useprefix=true,
  dashed=false,
  date=year, urldate=long,
  isbn=false, eprint=false,
  mincrossrefs=99,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{extradateonlycompcitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Awesome Journal},
  volume = 3
}
@article{a2,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Another Journal},
  volume = 3
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{a1,a2}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smith et al. 2020a, b]

---

A simple alternative to redefining the pretty complex cite macros in order to obtain "Author Yeara, Yearb" is to reset `\cbx@lastyear` at every citekey. (Of course changing the macros would be more efficient, but this solution is much shorter in the preamble.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  sorting=ynt,
  uniquename=false,uniquelist=minyear,
  maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=2, 
  useprefix=true,
  dashed=false,
  date=year, urldate=long,
  isbn=false, eprint=false,
  mincrossrefs=99,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Awesome Journal},
  volume = 3
}
@article{a2,
  author={John Smith and Mary Stuart and Peter Pan},
  year = 2020,
  journal = {Another Journal},
  volume = 3
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{a1,a2}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smith et al. 2020a, 2020b]

This solution would also work for `biblatex-ext` styles.